# Subclass NSApplication in Swift

Tags: swift, nsapplication

I created NSApplication subclass:

```
class MyApplication: NSApplication {
    override func sendEvent(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if theEvent.type == NSEventType.KeyUp && (theEvent.modifierFlags & .CommandKeyMask).rawValue != 0 {
            self.keyWindow?.sendEvent(theEvent)
        } else {
            super.sendEvent(theEvent)
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I changed "Principal class" in Info.plist to MyApplication and at the end in the Application Scene in Main.storyboard, I changed Application to MyApplication, too.

When I run application I get following message:

> Unable to find class: MyApplication, exiting

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try:

```
@objc(MyApplication)
class MyApplication: NSApplication {
```

OR, you have to set Info.plist like this.

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>YourAppName.MyApplication</string>
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There is no exact document about this, but [this description is corresponding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-XID_68):

> In order to preserve namespacing when a Swift class is used in Objective-C code, Swift classes are exposed to the Objective-C runtime with their fully qualified names. Therefore, when you work with APIs that operate on the string representation of a Swift class, you must include the fully qualified name of the class. For example, when you create a document–based Mac app, you provide the name of your NSDocument subclass in your app’s **Info.plist** file. In Swift, you must use the full name of your document subclass, including the module name derived from the name of your app or framework.

and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_36):

> When you use the `@objc(<#name#>)` attribute on a Swift class, the class is made available in Objective-C without any namespacing.

Comment: I found I needed the `@objc(MyClassName)` line and with that, the NSPrincipalClass value had to be `MyClassName` on Xcode 7.2 for 10.11 SDK. Nothing else seemed to work.

Comment: Well, the other approach DOES work with just name spacing, IF you can figure out the namespace. If the app name has a space in it, you need an underscore there. Who knows if it is non-English.

Comment: As of Xcode 11.3, I can confirm that <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME).MyClass</string> works with a Swift file.  It's important not to add the extension.