# Listen to keypress across all windows in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

How can I listen to NSEvents while my app has the focus, but independently of which window is active?

I'm not looking to listen to system-wide events, I only want to listen to single and/or modified keystrokes while my app has the focus, but all examples I could find, listen NSEvents from NSWindow or NSView.

My app has multiple windows and I want to catch all keystrokes while any of those windows are focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [`NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534971-addlocalmonitorforevents) API is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This will work, but it's overkill for this problem. See Alexander's answer for the correct approach.

---

Override [`NSApplication.sendEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428359-sendevent). This is the central dispatching method for all events in the application. You can determine which events you care about, and either consume them, or send them along using `super`. This is a documented override point in [NSApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication). It is not a hack.

Note that this requires subclassing NSApplication itself. It's not handled by the application delegate. For instructions on subclassing NSApplication in Swift, see [Subclass NSApplication in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144113/subclass-nsapplication-in-swift). (Read all the comments; the answer is a little messy. The key is setting [NSPrincipalClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW11).)

For more technical details, see the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html), which covers the whole architecture.

Comment: Hey Rob, do you know how this compares with the `NSApplication.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)` method? If I had to guest, the default implementation of `NSApplication.sendEvent` is what notifies those event handlers. (This would be easy enough to verify: override it and _don't_ call `super`, see if the `NSEvent` handlers stop working, but I don't have time to check that right now)

Comment: That's probably better. The last time I actually did this was on code originally built for 10.2, and I'm clearly way behind the times. :D Thanks.

Comment: That NSEevent API was introduced in 10.6, so that makes sense!